# Black block appears when mobile rotates to landscape

Tags: html, css, landscape

When viewing this site on my iPhone 4, everything looks how it should in portrait layout.  When rotated to view in landscape layout, there is one div that is responsible for creating a black block in the middle of the screen (below).

CSS is pretty basic

```
width: 100%;
img {
    margin-top: 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is - what is the intended behavior that you are seeking? What is the site?

Comment: Why is there a `width: 100%;` above your selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix.  My images were not resizing.

```
img { height: auto; max-width: 100%; }
```

Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Now used to media queries standard Devices

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi I experienced this problem in iphone and ipad,i used the following code in orientationchange triggered event/function

$(window).trigger("throttledresize");

```
$(document).bind("orientationchange", function(e){
      $(window).trigger("throttledresize")
});`
```